# Spring authentication with bcrypt

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'm trying to add bcrypt to a spring app of mine. Authentication works just fine without. But when I try to encode using bcrypt I get "Reason: Bad credentials" when trying to login.

My user model looks as follows.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users") // user is a reserved word in postgresql
public class User extends BaseEntity {
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();

    ...
    @Column(nullable=false)
    private String password;

    ...

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        String hashedPassword = passwordEncoder.encode(password);
        this.password = hashedPassword;
    }

    ...
}
```

My SecurityConfig looks as follows.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
...
}
```

Do the above seem right? Do I need to do more than what I've already done?

Comment: Silly question, but did you check whether your password in database is hashed?

Comment: Yes, as of now it looks like this: $2a$10$6k776rYtY.FN8tDfW08RyOgfsqDEkq3QpOCJcoVJF/oT/8FQcQ/oy

Comment: Already tried that. No difference.

Comment: Are you able paste the output of the password field?

Comment: $2a$10$jyaYvkHqgBhesyR8WwfQfe07eV/BVTXobwtI6dtxglGQZ0Zq4CYDi - That's with "password" as password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My bad for not posting enough code. Naturally my user model didn't tell the entire story. I also have a class called SecurityUser which I've posted below. Due to the copy constructor the password gets hashed twice.

```
public class SecurityUser extends User implements UserDetails {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 867280338717707274L;

    public SecurityUser(User user) {
        if(user != null)
        {
            this.setId(user.getId());
            this.setName(user.getName());
            this.setEmail(user.getEmail());
            this.setPassword(user.getPassword());
            this.setRoles(user.getRoles());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
        Set<Role> userRoles = this.getRoles();

        if(userRoles != null)
        {
            for (Role role : userRoles) {
                SimpleGrantedAuthority authority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName());
                authorities.add(authority);
            }
        }
        return authorities;
    }

...
}
```

I've made my passwordEncoder method public and promoted it to a bean so I can autowire it into my UserService which is shown below. That way I only have to change encoder in one place if I ever decide to do so.

```
@Service
public class UserService {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;


    public User create(User user) {
        String hashedPassword = passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword());
        user.setPassword(hashedPassword);
        return userRepository.save(user);
    }
...
}
```

Comment: Ok, but with this configuration, you will encode the password twice ! One time in your entity and one time in your `UserService`. And if your orm inject the property using the setter, you will encode the password another time. Remove your passwordEncoder property of your entity. This make no sense. If you separate your entities (and daos) in a different project of your services, you should not have the class `PasswordEncoder` in your entities.

Comment: Naturally I removed it from my model and only have it in my service. Thanks for your input.

Comment: Ok, update your first post with all you latest code. Add a edit section with your lastest update. By the way, I strongly recommand to separate your `SecurityUser` and `User`. `SecurityUser` should not extends your `User` but just implements `UserDetails`. Otherwise, you will be able to call the `UserService.create` method on a `SecurityUser` or to create `SecurityUser` from a other one. This 2 case should happend and, IMHO, this relation is not correct. Remove this inheritence in your code and maybe you will see what's wrong in your code.

Comment: The above code is working. I'm simply waiting until SO lets me accept my own answer.

Comment: My code is inspired by [this](http://www.sivalabs.in/2014/03/springmvc4-spring-data-jpa.html). What makes you say it's a bad idea to let SecurityUser inherit from User?

Comment: Because a security user should not contain any password. Even if it's machting a user, it's not dedicated for the same things. But, like i said, it's only IMHO. And you can wait a long time if you hope to vote your own answer !!

Comment: You do have a point. I'll reconsider my code. Do you perhaps have a link to an example with better code? As of this writing I can accept my answer in 12 hours.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would set it up.

User Table has 4 properties (amongst others)

1. id (auto increment)
2. username (or email_address) field
3. password field.
4. enabled (value will be either 1 or 0)

Role table (3 properties)

1. id (auto increment)
2. user_id (user table foreign key)
3. authority;

Create Java Entities for the two tables.

Spring Security Configuration Class looks like:

```
@Autowired 
public void  configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception { 
String usrsByUnameQry = "SELECT u.email_address, u.password, u.enabled FROM user u WHERE u.email_address=?"; 
3String authByUnameQry = "SELECT u.email_address, r.authority FROM user u, role r WHERE u.id=r.user_id AND u.email_address=?"; 

auth 
.eraseCredentials(false) 
.jdbcAuthentication() 
.dataSource(dataSource) 
.passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder()) 
.usersByUsernameQuery(usrsByUnameQry) 
.authoritiesByUsernameQuery(authByUnameQry); 
    } 

 @Override 
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception { 
      http 
         .formLogin() 
            .usernameParameter("username") //username property defined in html form
            .passwordParameter("password") //password property defined in html form
              // url that holds login form 
              .loginPage("/signin") 
              .loginProcessingUrl("/signin/authenticate") 
              .failureUrl("/loginfail") 
              // Grant access to users to the login page
              .permitAll() 
              .and() 
          .logout() 
            .logoutUrl("/signout") 
            .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID") 
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/signin") 
            .and() 
                   .authorizeRequests() 
                .antMatchers("/foo/**").permitAll()//Grant access to all (no auth reuired) 
                .antMatchers("/").hasAnyAuthority("ROLE_USER","ROLE_ADMIN") //Grant access to only users with role "ROLE_USER" or "ROLE_ADMIN"  
  } 

 @Bean(name = "authenticationManager") 
 @Override 
 public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception { 
    return super.authenticationManagerBean(); 
   } 

 @Bean   
 public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){ 
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(); 
    } 

@Bean 
public TextEncryptor textEncryptor(){ 
    return Encryptors.noOpText(); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. I've choosen a somewhat different path. By implementing a custom UserDetailsService class you can get rid of the sql in your security conf.